# $\overline{conv}(C)$, where $C = \{ e _{1}, \cdots e _{n} \}$, $e _{i} \in \ell ^{p, \infty}$ is diametral

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $C = \{ e _{1}, \cdots e _{n} \}$, where each $e _{i}$ are unit vectors  in $\ell ^{p, \infty}$, and $1 < p < \infty$. I want prove that $\overline{conv}(C)$ is diametral. My doubt is: $\Vert x - y \Vert _{p, \infty} \leqslant 1$ for all $x, y \in \overline{conv}(C)$, where 
\begin{align*}
\Vert x \Vert _{p, \infty} = \max \{ \Vert x  ^{+}\Vert _{p}, \Vert x ^{-} \Vert _{p} \}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
(x ^{+}) ^{i} = \max \{ x _{i}, 0 \} = \frac{\vert x _{i}\vert + x _{i}}{2} \quad \mbox{and} \quad (x ^{-}) ^{i} = \max \{ -x _{i}, 0 \} = \frac{\vert x _{i}\vert - x _{i}}{2}
\end{align*}
for all $x _{i} \in \ell ^{p, \infty}$?.

Comment: Are you assuming anything about the $e_i$, like $\|e_i\|_{p,\infty}\le1$? And is your actual question whether $\|x-y\|_{p,\infty}\le 1$ for $x,y$ in the closed convex hull of $C$?

Comment: Yes, I want to know if $\Vert x - y \Vert _{p, \infty} \leqslant 1$ for all $x, y$ in the closed convexd hull of $C$. How $\overline{conv}(C)$ is the smallest closed and convex set that contains C, particularly $\overline{conv}(C) \subseteq B _{\ell ^{p,\infty}}$.

Comment: But what are the $e_i$??? What if $n=1$ and $e_1$ is some vector of norm 1000?? [I half guess that you want to refer to the unit vectors; if so, please say so.] And which $p$ do you consider?

Comment: yes, each $e _{i}$ are unit vectors and $1 < p < \infty$.

Comment: Couldn't you argue that $C$ is not diametral because it's compact?

Comment: no, exists subset of  some reflexive spaces that can be compact, convex and diametrals with diameter positive. An example of that are uniformy nons-square spaces. I want prove that $\ell ^{p,\infty}$ aren't normal structure and to prove that, I want prove that $\overline{conv}(C)$ is a subset of $\ell ^{p,\infty}$ is closed, bounded, convex and diametral with positive diameter, and I want know if $\Vert x - y \Vert _{p, \infty} \leqslant 1$, because if $\Vert x - y \Vert _{p, \infty} \leqslant 1$, then $\operatorname{diam}(\overline{conv}(C)) = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\mathrm{diam}( \overline {\mathrm{conv}}(C) ) = \mathrm{diam}(C)$, and note that $\|e_i-e_j\|_{p,\infty}=1$ for $i\neq j$. This proves your inequality $\|x-y\|_{p,\infty}\le 1$.

However, you won't get diametrality from this. On page 39 of Goebel and Kirk's "Topics in metric fixed point theory" you will find a proof of the fact, due to Brodskii and Milman, that compact convex sets have normal structure. Note that your set actually lives in a finite-dimensional space.

Comment: thanks for help me :)